# Canon Pixma iP5200 gone haywire

Tags: printing, printer, ubuntu-14.04, canon-pixma

I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 and decided to move my printer to the server. I did install CUPS, but didn't try installing any drivers. I tried printing the test page but it got stuck during "Sending data to printer...".

Ever since then the printer indicator lights (green and orange) have been flashing alternately (for 11 times after which the green light was on noticeably longer).

I checked the manual and it says that there are faulty parts in the printer that need to be replaced, but I find that hard to believe. It has to be some kind of software error.

Is it possible that some of the printers circuits really got corrupted?

Is there a way I can reset the printer to factory defaults or recover it from this state in any way?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by installing CUPS but not drivers?  In order to select your printer and send a print job to it, a driver had to be set up.  If CUPS already has a driver, you still need to identify the printer to get it into your list of available printers.  A different printer driver could have been selected, in which case the output could be corrupted or it might not print.  However, that shouldn't damage the printer.  Disconnect the printer from the computer, unplug the printer from the wall, and let it sit a few minutes.  Then plug it back into power and try the self-test.

Comment: I installed CUPS and selected the correct make and model of the printer and tried to print test page using browser interface. I had the printer disconnected from power for an hour but it still turned on into the same state.

Comment: The test page is sent from CUPS, so that won't differentiate hardware vs. software errors.  The printer has a self-test (typically triggered by holding down a button while turning the printer on.  Shut the printer off, disconnect it from the computer, unplug it from power for a few minutes, then, while still disconnected from the computer, plug it in and run the self test.

Comment: I tried turning it on in the service mode (let's call it that) and depending on number of times pressed the resume button, different thing should happen. However, regardless of number of times I pushed the button it always went back to green-orange flashing.

Comment: Download the service manual (I posted a link in my answer).  If it is something you can diagnose and fix yourself, it will be in there.  If you can't correct it with the guidance in the service manual, contact Canon tech support.  If the printer is new, I would consider just exchanging it.  If it's still under warranty, Canon should fix or replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pixma iP5200 is a GDI printer which requires the Operating System of the PC to convert the page into dots on the paper. These printers cannot be used without their own specific driver. Without a driver, I suspect the CUPS test print would be sent to the printer as PostScript, which the Pixma does not understand.

Try installing the correct driver and see if it then works.

You may need to clear Ubuntu's print queue to ensure the job is not resent when the printer powers up again. So, switch off, clear the queue and switch back on. That should let the printer power up correctly, unless it does indeed have a hardware error.

If you do want to perform a factory reset, try the following (from [this link)](https://howtohardreset.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/reset-canon-pixma-ip4200-ip5200-ip6000-ip8500/):

1. Turn off the Printers.
2. Hold RESUME button, click POWER.
3. Hold button RESUME, release POWER
4. Then press the RESUME button again twice.
5. Release all the buttons.
6. Indicator led in green and stay green.
7. Turn off the printer POWER button.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the service manual for your printer.  Eleven flashes is a failure during automatic printhead alignment:

[image: error message]

Note that after fixing the problem, you will need to manually rerun the alignment.  If the items listed don't fix the problem, I would contact Canon tech support.

The service manual can be downloaded [here](http://pdfretriever.com/ref_sien.php?ID=4255439&lg=E&h=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&src=15).  It contains a lot of information and procedures that may be helpful.

Comment: I read the manual, it's not it. The problem seems to be confusing the error reporting parts of the printer or something since I doubt it's the printer head alignment and that error doesn't go away after preforming the described procedure.

Comment: @Karlovsky120: Sounds like it's time to get a bigger hammer from Canon tech support.  :-)